# How do I use Selenium (Java) By with an existing element

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to use the following selenium to look for a child in a parent element and this works great

```
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(parent, By.xpath(xpath))
```

Now I want a method that returns ALL the elements that match the xPath, however, to my surprise the signature requires a `By` instead of the `WebElement` [I would expect](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfNestedElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-org.openqa.selenium.By-).

How can I convert my WebElement to a by to get the other elements?

Comment: "to my surprise the signature requires a `By`", **which** signature?

Comment: @acdcjunior See the link in the desc `presenceOfNestedElementsLocatedBy`

Comment: "How can I convert my WebElement to a by to get the other elements?" -> you can't, that's not possible in vanilla selenium. Maybe [a framework on top of it](http://github.com/seleniumquery/seleniumquery) could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for you to get all the child Elements by Passing `BY`:

```
public class Demo {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\eclipse\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://google.com");


        By x = By.xpath("//div"); //or your By.xpath(xpath)
        List<WebElement> allItem = getChildElements(x);

        System.out.println(allItem.size());


        for(WebElement item : allItem){

            System.out.println(item.getText());
        }



    }

    public static List<WebElement> getChildElements(By x){

        List<WebElement> allElems = driver.findElements(x);
        return allElems;

    }
}
```

Comment: I understand how to use a By, that wasn't my question. How do I use a by when I have a WebElement and not the Xpath string or element name or any other info

Comment: @Jackie : But in order to get a parent element you need to have locator of some kind first

Answer (score 0):

Try doing class casting and proceed with. The code will look something similar to this.

```
WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
WebElement child = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(parent, (By)child));
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: presenceOfNestedElementsLocatedBy is what I was talking not presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy. It requires parent to be a by.

Comment: @Jackie Does the class casting doesn't working for you?

Comment: this has already been made explicit in the comments and also the like that I originally posted (Notice I originally said the code I posted works fine). I haven't tried casting but I have looked at the Java docs and I don't see web element inheriting By or vice versa but I will try to confirm today.